# Check claims (email) before creating a new cookie, without asp. core identity store using asp net core social login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, oauth, asp.net-identity

I'm working on my hobby project where I'have implemented social login via Google.

now I want to prevent this so that only certain user can sign in into the app, As I found that there is no way to restrict this on google OAuth side, So I have added a table to store the email and role.

if the email address is not found in that table I want to prevent a user from signing.

```
            services
           .AddAuthentication(options =>
           {
               options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           })
           .AddCookie()
           .AddGoogle(googleOption =>
           {

               googleOption.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientID"]; ;
               googleOption.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
               googleOption.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
               {
                   context.HandleResponse();
                   return context.Response.WriteAsync("<script>window.close();</script>");
               };
               googleOption.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthEvents
               {
                   OnTicketReceived = async ctx =>
                   {
                       string emailAddress = ctx.Principal.
                                               FindFirstValue("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress");
                       var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
                       var roles = await db.EmailRoles.Where(c => c.Email == emailAddress).ToListAsync();
                       if (roles.Count > 1)                           
                       {
                           var claims = new List<Claim>();
                           foreach (var item in roles)
                           {
                               claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Role));
                           }
                           var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                           ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                       }
                   }
               };
           });
```

Comment: I think that you are going to have to test this at the time the user Logs in.  So your login form will allow them to login however once they have gone though the google process you can then check it to decide if you want to allow them to login.  If not then you remove the signin and display them an error message.

Comment: So in the above code where I can check and prevent asp.net core from generation cookie. I believe that must be in the addCookie section, but I don't how to do it.

Comment: You don't do it in the above code thats just setting it up.   You would do it in your login methods

Comment: @DaImTo the above code is that I have in my startup, except that, I have just one controller action that redirects to the google for authentication. I'm not using identity store to store the user related information, I just have one table that stores the list of email address along with the role of the user who will be allowed to log in.

Everything is the same as it is in the blazor-workshop. I just one to add one email check before login that user.
https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/src/BlazingPizza.Server/UserController.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `OnCreatingTicket`.  this will allow you to test the users as their logging in.  In this example only gmail.com emails would be allowed to login anyone else would be kicked out

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            options.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = context =>
                {
                    string domain = context.User.Value<string>("domain");
                    if (domain != "gmail.com")
                        throw new GoogleAuthenticationException("You must sign in with a gmail.com email address");

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```